# How do I make an outline or box around a download link?

Tags: html, css

I tried looking online, but I couldn't find anything. Please help!

I tried some methods that were supposed to work, but they did not.

Comment: Please provide some code so that others can get an idea about what you have tried.

Answer (score 1):

Use the attribute selector and apply the style

```css
a[download] {
  outline: 2px solid orange;
}
```

```html
<a href="/foo.jpg" download>Download</a>
```